# how to store file contents to iphone's internal memory using xcode?

Tags: ios4

how to store file contents to iphone's internal memory using xcode ?

I want to store XML file to iPhone's internal memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read hold the xml data in NSData and store the file in private folder ( avaible only for application )

below is code for saving file

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSMutableString* str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:300];
        [str appendString:documentsDirectory];
        [str appendString:@"/"];
        [str appendString:aName];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [/*NSData*/ writeToFile:str atomically:YES];

        if(str)
        {
            [str release];
            str = nil;

        }
        if(fileManager)
        {
            [fileManager release];
            fileManager = nil;
        }

        [pool release];
```